# Why can't use Added and EnumerationCompleted Event in uwp>

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

[image]

i make some IoT project, i followed microsoft example and guides but i can't use Added and EnmerationCompleted Event

Please let me know if there are any mistakes or let me know if there are any other codes I don't know

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "cannot use". Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, the explanation was insufficient.
I mean, many examples use events like the picture above, but in my code, referencing an event gives an error.

Comment: 오류의 내용은 CS1545 Property, Indexer, or event 'DeviceWatcher.Added' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'DeviceWatcher.add_Added(typedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformation>)

Comment: What I'm curious about is whether the syntax of the example is not available in my version of UWP anymore.

Comment: Something is weird with the way the project is configured that it can't see Windows Runtime events. Try creating a brand new UWP project, see if the problem occurs there. If not, then compare the project configuration settings.